# Using scapy sniff on reboot in Raspberrypi (Systemd)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scapy, systemd

TL;DR: Why does Scapy's sniff not run at reboots from systemd?

I have the following code running on my RPI3 that specifically looks for network requests. This uses the inbuilt ETH0 wifi:

**monitorConnections.py**

```
def arp_detect(pkt):

    print("Starting ARP detect")
    logging.debug('Starting ARP detect')

    if pkt.haslayer(ARP):


        if pkt[ARP].op == 1: #network request
            PHONE_name = "Unknown"
            PHONE_mac_address = ""

            if pkt[ARP].hwsrc in known_devices.keys():
                print ("Known Phone Detected")
                logging.debug('Known Phone Detected')

                # Grab name and mac address
                PHONE_mac_address = pkt[ARP].hwsrc
                PHONE_name = known_devices[PHONE_mac_address]

                print ('Hello ' + PHONE_name)
                logging.debug('Hello ' + PHONE_name)

            else:
                # Grab mac address, log these locally

                print ("Unknown Phone Detected")
                logging.debug('Unknown Phone Detected')

                PHONE_mac_address = pkt[ARP].hwsrc

        print (pkt[ARP].hwsrc)

print("Start!")
print (sniff(prn=arp_detect, filter="arp", store=0))
```

When I run this via the command

```
python2 monitorConnections.py
```

This runs as designed, however I have been trying to put this in a daemon, conscious that it needs to run after the internet connection has been established. I have the following setting in my service:

**MonitorConnections.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor Connections
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 -u monitorConnections.py
ExecStop=pkill -9 /usr/bin/autossh
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Shared/MonitorPhones
Restart=always
User=root

StandardOutput=console
StandardError=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In order to find the services that I need my script to run after, I ran this command:

```
systemctl list-units --no-pager
```

To find the following services to add to my service under 'After' - these corresspond with the ethernet 
services (I imagine!)

```
sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device
sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device
```

As far as I can tell, this is running successfully. When I save everything and run the following:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart monitorConnections
```

This kickstarts the script beautifully. I have then set my script to run at reboot like so:

```
sudo systemctl enable monitorConnections
```

And reboot, I can see that it runs the print statement "Start", however then does not seem to run anything within the 'sniff' command, however when running

```
sudo systemctl -l status monitorConnections
```

I can see that the script is active - so it has not errored!

My question: Why is it that scapy's sniff does not seem to run at reboot? Have I missed something out

I'm honestly at the end of my wits as to what is wrong - any help about this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks very similar to your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163658/using-arp-in-python-script-run-by-systemctl-not-working). If you found a solution to that question, please post it. If that question is no longer necessary (in favor of this more detailed one), please delete the former.

Comment: My bad - after a bit of debugging I've narrowed it down to the specific function - hence the new question. Have removed the previous one, regardless.

Comment: Are you sure the script is still active and loaded ? I would use `ps aux python...` to verify. If there is no **exception handling** in your code (and **logging**) now is a good time to add it, to make the script more robust, and debugging easier. What I like to do is start cron jobs in GNU screen sessions ([here's how](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78020/190343)). After the system has booted up you can attach to the screen session and see what the script is doing. Plus, you can **log** all the console output to a file. When you have done that, no need to guess, just look at the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPI3's wifi driver does not have monitoring mode. After weeks of debugging, this was narrowed down to be the issue. I hope this helps someone else.